# Problems extending a Hibernate Validator constraint

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to extend the behavior of the [`@NotBlank` constraint](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/5.1/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.java) to apply to `URI`s by making a custom constraint called `@NotBlankUri`.

Here's my constraint annotation:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotBlankUriValidator.class)
public @interface NotBlankUri {
    String message() default "{project.model.NotBlankUri.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and here is the `ConstraintValidator`:

```
public class NotBlankUriValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotBlankUri, URI> {

    public void initialize(NotBlankUri annotation) {
    }

    public boolean isValid(URI uri, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        NotBlankValidator nbv = new NotBlankValidator();
        return nbv.isValid(uri.toString(), context);
    }
}
```

Problem is that the `isValid()` method on the `ConstraintValidator` is getting `null` values for the `URI` argument. I thought this wasn't supposed to happen given the fact that `@NotBlank` itself [is annotated `@NotNull`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/5.1/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.java#L45). That not being the case, I tried adding `@NotNull` as a meta-annotation to my `@NotBlankUri`, but that didn't have the desired effect either. How can I make my annotation constraint behave like `@NotBlank`, which seems to be stacking on top of the behavior of `@NotNull`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, you can't use the `@NotBlank` annotation on a datatype that is not a String.

> public @interface NotBlank
>
> Validate that the annotated string is not null or empty. The difference to NotEmpty is that trailing whitespaces are getting ignored.

So if you declared your validator to validate a String, everything would be fine and you could write your annotation like this:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotBlankUriValidator.class)
@NotBlank    
public @interface NotBlankUri {
    String message() default "{project.model.NotBlankUri.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

If you are deadset on using the URI class <sup>1</sup> you need to perform custom validation logic yourself like this:

Annotation:

```
@NotNull(message="URI must not be null")
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotBlankUriValidator.class)
public @interface NotBlankUri {
    String message() default "URI must not be blank";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator:

```
public class NotBlankUriValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotBlankUri, URI> {
    public void initialize(NotBlankUri annotation) {
    }

    public boolean isValid(URI uri, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean isValid = true;
        System.out.println("URI: " + uri);
        //Leave null checks to your @NotNull constraint.
        //This is only here to prevent a NullPointerException on the next check.
        if(uri == null){
            return true;
        }
        if(uri.toString().isEmpty()){
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

I ran the above with a test harness:

```
public class UriContainer {

    public UriContainer(URI uri){
        this.uri = uri;
    }
    @NotBlankUri
    private URI uri;

    public URI getUri() {
        return uri;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException{
    UriContainer filledContainer = new UriContainer(new URI("Stuff"));
    UriContainer emptyContainer = new UriContainer(new URI(""));
    UriContainer nullContainer = new UriContainer(null);
    
    Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    
    Set<ConstraintViolation<UriContainer>> filledViolations = validator
            .validate(filledContainer);
    
    Set<ConstraintViolation<UriContainer>> emptyViolations = validator
            .validate(emptyContainer);
    
    Set<ConstraintViolation<UriContainer>> nullViolations = validator
            .validate(nullContainer);
    
    System.out.println("Filled: ");
    filledViolations.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("Empty: ");
    emptyViolations.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("Null: ");
    nullViolations.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    
}
```

which output the following violations:

> URI: Stuff 
> URI: 
> URI: null 
> Filled:  
> Empty:  
> ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='URI must not be blank', propertyPath=uri, rootBeanClass=class sandbox.UriContainer, messageTemplate='URI must not be blank'} 
> Null:  
> ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='URI must not be null', propertyPath=uri, rootBeanClass=class sandbox.UriContainer, messageTemplate='URI must not be null'}

As you can see, this allows you to output different error messages based on if the URI is blank or null. Just make sure if you are using a `javax.validation` annotation you check which datatype you operate on.

<sub>1: which by the way, performs validation when you construct the object, and will throw a `URISyntaxException` if the String passed to the constructor violates RFC 2396</sub>

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for this. Should have done these tests myself. Will review carefully and +1/accept I am sure.